# Custom Admin Button OnClick Add more Group Of Fields to Section

Tags: system.xml, addfield

I Created Custom **IconSlider** Module That Can Be controlled from **Store-Configuration**.

**Each slider Have the Same 3 Fields (Name,URL,Image).**

i added a few groups With that fields But every time i want to add 1 more slider i need to copy and past a new group with the same fields and thats not really smart..

So i manage to add new field **type = "Button"** that show at the bottom of the groups.

**what i am trying to do is When i click on this button that he will add automaticlly a New Group With Empty Fields(Name,URL,Image).**

**etc/adminhtml/System.xml**

```
       <field id="AddNewFields" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config\Button</frontend_model>
       </field>
```

**Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config\Button.php**

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config;
 use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
 use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
 use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;
 class Button extends Field
{
protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::System/Config/Button.phtml';
public function __construct(Context $context, array $data = [])
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function render(AbstractElement $element)
{
    $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
    return parent::render($element);
}
protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
{
    return $this->_toHtml();
}
public function getCustomUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('router/controller/action');
}
public function getButtonHtml()
{
    $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button')->setData(['id' => 'CustomButtonAddFields', 'label' => __('Add New Icon Slider'),]);
    return $button->toHtml();
}
public function addCustomfield(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset $fieldset)
{
    
}
```

}

**Vendor_Module/view/adminhtml/templates/System/Config/Button.phtml**

```
<?php
/* @var \Vendor\Module\Block\System\config\Button $block */

$controller = $block->getCustomUrl();
echo $block->getButtonHtml();
?>

<script>
require([
    'jquery'
], function($){
    $('#CustomButtonAddFields').on('click', function() {
        alert('Clicked!~');
    })
});
```

As You Can See I Created A New Function At **Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config\Button.php** Called **addCustomfield** And I want To Activate This Function From The Button.Phtml OnClick Event.

**Thats How Its Look In The Admin Panel :**

Click Here : [Preview](https://prnt.sc/16ku67b)

so what Should I Do In This **addCustomfield** Function ?

Ty .

Answer (score 0):

**system.xml**

```
<field id="add_new_fields" translate="label comment" type="button" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config\Button</frontend_model>
</field>
```

**Button.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Collect extends Field
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::System/Config/button.phtml';

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Remove scope label
     *
     * @param  AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }

    /**
     * Return element html
     *
     * @param  AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Return ajax url for collect button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAjaxUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('add_new_fields/system_config/collect'); //here you can set your configration path
    }

    /**
     * Generate collect button html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button'
        )->setData(
            [
                'id' => 'collect_button',
                'label' => __('Collect Data'),
            ]
        );

        return $button->toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

**button.phtml**

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'prototype'
    ], function(jQuery){
        jQuery('#collect_button').click(function () {
            alert('This is Testing');
        });

    });
</script>

<?php echo $block->getButtonHtml() ?>
```

Comment: Can You Be More Specific Please ?
i notice     public function getAjaxUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('add_new_fields/system_config/collect'); //here you can set your configration path
    }

But How Does This Create More Fields ?

Comment: section_id/group_id/field_id

Comment: if you add your config full code I will add your config path

Comment: I added My system.xml file ^

Comment: iconslider/sliders/addnewfields try this path

Comment: hi past this path into getAjaxURL and nothing change ..

Comment: I need to Do Somthing With that AjaxUrl ?

Comment: no or chnage thi button id on getButtonHtml() this function replace "collect_button" to "addnewfields"

Comment: i replace the button id at getButtonHtml() to addnewfields and still no Group Was Created

Comment: 1st thing in system.xml group_id , section_id or field_id is always in lowercase

Comment: ok i did change them to lowercase

Comment: after change apply my code and check

Comment: sorry man steel Dont Working..
can you post the full code to let me compare with mine, becuse i did the same as you comment me

Comment: Let me check your code please attach your code

Answer (score 0):

System.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="kravitz" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
        <label>Kravitz</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="iconslider" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Icon Slider</label>
        <tab>kravitz</tab>
        <resource>vendor_module::config_IconSLider</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
            <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Module Enable</label>
                <comment>Set To 'Yes' If You Want The Icon Slider Module To Be display At Frontend.</comment>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Block title</label>
                <comment>This is Optional, Leave Empty If You Dont Want Any Title To Be Display On Icon Slider block.
                if Not Empty The Title will display At Frontend.</comment>

            </field>
        </group>
        <group id="sliders" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>Icon Sliders</label>
            <group id="generalslider" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Icon 1</label>
                <field id="text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Optional, display The Icon Name</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Url Link</label>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Optional, Attached The Link To The Icon Name !</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="imageupload" translate="label" type="image" sortOrder="1" showInStore="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
                    <label>Upload Icon Image</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
                    <upload_dir config="system">IconSlider</upload_dir>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Requierd !, If Ther Is No file Chosen The Slider Will Not Display !</comment>
                </field>
            </group>

            <group id="generalslider2" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Icon 2</label>
                <field id="text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Optional, display The Icon Name</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Url Link</label>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Optional, Attached The Link To The Icon Name !</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="imageupload" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Image" sortOrder="1" showInStore="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
                    <label>Upload Icon Image</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
                    <upload_dir config="system">IconSlider</upload_dir>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Requierd !, If Ther Is No file Chosen The Slider Will Not Display !</comment>
                </field>
            </group>

            <group id="generalslider3" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Icon 3</label>
                <field id="text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Optional, display The Icon Name</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Url Link</label>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Optional, Attached The Link To The Icon Name !</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="imageupload" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Image" sortOrder="1" showInStore="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
                    <label>Upload Icon Image</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
                    <upload_dir config="system">IconSlider</upload_dir>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Requierd !, If Ther Is No file Chosen The Slider Will Not Display !</comment>
                </field>
            </group>

            <group id="generalslider4" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Icon 4</label>
                <field id="text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Optional, display The Icon Name</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Url Link</label>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Optional, Attached The Link To The Icon Name !</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="imageupload" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Image" sortOrder="1" showInStore="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
                    <label>Upload Icon Image</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
                    <upload_dir config="system">IconSlider</upload_dir>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Requierd !, If Ther Is No file Chosen The Slider Will Not Display !</comment>
                </field>
            </group>

            <group id="generalslider5" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Icon 5</label>
                <field id="text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Optional, display The Icon Name</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Url Link</label>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Optional, Attached The Link To The Icon Name !</comment>
                </field>

                <field id="imageupload" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Image" sortOrder="1" showInStore="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
                    <label>Upload Icon Image</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
                    <upload_dir config="system">IconSlider</upload_dir>
                    <comment>This Filed Is Requierd !, If Ther Is No file Chosen The Slider Will Not Display !</comment>
                </field>
            </group>

            <field id="addnewfieldsbutton" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <frontend_model>Vendor\module\Block\System\Config\Button</frontend_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

Button.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\System\Config;

 use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
 use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
 use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

 class Button extends Field
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::System/Config/Button.phtml';

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(Context $context, array $data = [])
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Remove scope label
 *
 * @param  AbstractElement $element
 * @return string
 */
public function render(AbstractElement $element)
{
    $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
    return parent::render($element);
}

/**
 * Return element html
 *
 * @param  AbstractElement $element
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
{
    return $this->_toHtml();
}

/**
 * Return ajax url for collect button
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAjaxUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('iconslider/sliders/addnewfields'); //here you can set your configration path
}

/**
 * Generate collect button html
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getButtonHtml()
{
    $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button')->setData(['id' => 'addnewfields', 'label' => __('Add New Icon Slider'),]);
    return $button->toHtml();
}

 }
```

Button.phtml

```
<?php
/* @var \Vendor\Module\Block\System\config\Button $block */
?>

   <script>
    require([
    'jquery',
    'prototype'
], function($){
    $('#addnewfields').click(function () {
        alert('This is Testing');
    });

});
   </script>

  <?php echo $block->getButtonHtml() ?>
```